# different results in object size?

Tags: r, objectsize

```
require(lobstr)

x <- lapply(1:50, function(i) c(rep("abc", i)))
```

1. `obj_size(x) ## 13,352 B`
2. `sum(sapply(x, obj_size)) + 50*8 + 56 ## 16104 B 8 is pointer size, 56 is initial space`

why the results are different?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did try to replicate your problem with base R object.size function,

```
x <- lapply(1:50, function(i) c(rep("abc", i)))
object.size(x)
sum(sapply(x, object.size)) + 50*8 + 56
```

I found below result. there does not seems to be much of a difference here might be 8 bytes here and there but it's nearly the same. I don't think it would make any significant difference in with such a small difference.

[image]

Comment: thanks. so it means, there may be some bugs in obj_size function?

Comment: Yeah might be.. though I will check how these two functions works.. might be the internal working/calculation itself is different which leading the different results

Comment: I think maybe the difference come from the environment used to calculate. According to ?obj_size() `it never counts the size of the global environment, the base environment, the empty environment, or any namespace.`